# How do I make my application as default for editing a kind of files?

Tags: java, windows

I created a java application and works as expected. Currently, I have to open the application myself and open the files I need to edit. How can I open those files directly with my Java application from a file browser and emulate the behavior described previously for my application opening a file? When I do it, the application is executed but the JTextArea with the contents of the file is blank.

My application was converted into an exe file using Launch4j.

Comment: This might help you out: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html setting as default would be something the user has to do I think.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a programming question. This seems like it's a system configuration issue -- that'd be for Super User. The only programmer-y part would be making sure you can launch your program with a text document as a startup parameter -- and that's a separate issue from what you're actually asking.

Comment: No what I mean is I coded the program, but whenever I try to open a text file using it, NOT from inside of the program, it won't work. It just opens up the program with blank text. George Stocker you might be right about the "programmer-y part", but I'm not sure what to do for that. I'll try changing it

Comment: I edited your question. I think it makes more sense now. You're open to edit it and provide necessary info for this as well.

Comment: Does you program inspect the command line arguement for the file it should open ?

Comment: Isn't that what String[] args is meant for in main method? Pass a path to the file and then do your job.

Comment: Can someone give me an example for the String[] args part?

Comment: Well I fixed the problem. Thanks for the little bit of help.

Comment: @Baws If you've solved the problem, write the code you've used to solve the problem as an answer and post it.

Comment: Please don't edit your question and put `[Solved]` in there; that's what answers and accepting an answer are for.